# Creation of a particular column in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a number of rows divided into groups. To each row from each group is assigned a number, and rows from the same group have the same number. In another column I have some different data associated for each row. What i need is to put in a new column the biggest data number from the last mentioned column for every group. Example:

Column A is the group number

Column B is the data I have

Column C is the biggest data in every group sorted from the first group to the last one

```
A       B         C
1      24        75
1      75        95
1      52        65
2      36
2      12
2      95
3      32
3      65
3      41
```

I need to automate the creation of column C

Comment: are the groups always 1,2,3... or different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by your example, then the formula will be:

```
=MAX(INDIRECT(
      CELL("address", INDEX($B$1:$B$9, MATCH(ROW(), $A$1:$A$9, 0)))&":"&
      CELL("address", INDEX($B$1:$B$9, MATCH(ROW(), $A$1:$A$9, 1)))
     ))
```

### Explanation

`INDEX( ... )` retrieves the value in a group equal to current row. If you are in row 1, then it will retrieve the value of group 1.

***Interesting thing*** is using `0` for `match_type` returns the **first** matched value, while `1` returns the **last** value.

`CELL("address", ... )` returns the address of cell returned by the `INDEX`, that is **always** the first and last matching value of the group.

`INDIRECT( ... &":"& ... )` converts the string formed to a range. For example for group 1 it will be `INDIRECT("$B$1:$B$3")`

`MAX( ... )` finds the highest value in the range returned by `INDIRECT`