# Excel - Finding the nth largest value for each member of a list

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've got a heap of data which consists of values at different sites like this:

```
Site  Value
A      1
A      2
A      5
A      7
B      5
B      7
B      11
```

The number of values at each site may vary. I want to extract the nth largest value for each site, e.g,. for n=2

```
Site  Value
A     2
B     7
```

Is there an easier way of doing this than manually adding a couple of blank rows between each site and using LARGE?

Comment: You can probably use `RANK()=n` in some constellation with IFs

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap LARGE within an IF and create an Array Formula to get the nth largest value from a subset. A single formula shall work for each site.

[image]

In Columns A & B is your data. Create a Master List of Sites in say Column D and put the nth larget qualifier value say 2,3 4 whatever is needed in column E. Now in F put the formula

```
=LARGE(IF($A$1:$A$7=D1,$B$1:$B$7,""),E1)
```

Enclose it as an array formula by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER and drag it down.

Answer (score 0):

Related to [my answer on another question](https://superuser.com/a/1205685/456385).

You can build an array or range using combination of these formulas

`INDEX( value_range, MATCH( lookup_value, lookup_range, 0 ))` for the start of the range

`INDEX( value_range, MATCH( lookup_value, lookup_range, 1 ))` for the end of the range

So, in your question, you can use this combined with `LARGE`

```
=LARGE(INDIRECT(
   INDEX($B$1:$B$7, MATCH($C1, $A$1:$A$7, 0))&":"
   INDEX($B$1:$B$7, MATCH($C1, $A$1:$A$7, 1))
   ), 2)
```

***Note:*** You need to sort the sites. Ascending or descending is fine, just to make sure the sites are grouped up.

Where column `B` refers to your list of values, and column `A` to your list of sites.

`$C1` refers to the site you want to get the nth value (in your example that should be "A")

Comment: This assumes that all the data for each site is grouped together in the table. If the data is not organized this way, the formula will be prone to errors.

Comment: Thank you, I will update the answer to include a warning for that.